# Translation of ayah 5:6

Tags: quran, quran-translation

Assalam aleykum.

***... But if you are ill or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women and do not find water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and hands with it...*** (Quran 5:6 - Sahih International)

I would like to ask those who knows Arabic. The part ***"one of you comes from the place of relieving himself"***. It is clear that when you urinate then this case falls under the part of ayah. So you must do ablution. But what if after urinating drops of urine come out and after ablution is done. Does this case fall under the part of ayah?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The word **" الغائط"** originally means: "a deep stable place" which refer to the place where people used to go for getting rid of waste liquid or waste matter of body. This sentence **"او جائ احد منکم من الغائط"** is a polite expression implying that “after getting rid of waste liquid and matter of body" one has to make Wodhu. According to **GENERAL ACCEPTED CONCEPT (URF)** this part of the verse is saying that what invalidates Wodhu is urine itself or stool itself. So if somebody (who had been on the state of Taharah) came from restroom without urinating, he would not tall into this category. On the other hand if someone urinated without going to the restroom, he would fall into this category.

As a result URF does not translate this verse word by word so coming, going or crossing restroom will not make any difference as long as the waste liquid or waste matter does not come out of the body.

Comment: So the word refers to a place where people go **with the intention** to get rid of waste of body. But if people go to the place with other intentions then this does not fall under the ayah. **So drops of urine does not fall under this ayah because it is unintended.**

Comment: As I explained in my answer, neither going to or coming from that place, nor the "intention" of getting rid of waste are associated with this rule. Moreover, what part of the verse saying that this rule will not apply to those urinating without any intention?

Comment: Because the ayah talks about coming from "a deep stable place", where, as you explained, people go to relieve themselves (i.e. with the intention to relieve themselves). And it is clear that no matter what place a person goes with this intention then that makes the place a "place of relieving" for that person. And wherever person goes without the intention then the place is not a "place of relieving" for this person. But in case of drops of urine not only you don't have the intention even relieving does not take place.

Comment: The verse is free from the stipulation of intention so it conclude all cases whether getting rid of waste matter took place intentionally or unintentionally. If this stipulation had something to do with the rule, the All-wise lawmaker would've mentioned it.